# HTML in language files

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I made custom validation errors for an extension. Now I want to add an HTML link to an error message. tried to put HTML in language files (locallang.xlf) but it doesn't work.

Is there a way around this ?

Comment: More details please. How do you output `HTML`? Validation in backend or frontend? I think you need to use `CDATA` in `xlf` if you put htere `HTML`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use CDATA to encapsulate the HTML:

```
<target><![CDATA[Here is <a href="https://...">useful info</a>]]></target>
```

You should consider generating the link URI from the outside and pass it as argument. Your translation could then look like this:

```
<target><![CDATA[Here is <a href="%s">useful info</a>]]></target>
```

In a Fluid template you would then do this:

```
<f:translate key="translation-id" arguments="{0: '{f:uri.typolink(...)}'}"/>
```

This would have the advantage that you can freely customize the link e.g. via TypoScript constants/setup.

Answer (score 4):

Final step you should wrap the **f:translate** in a **f:format.raw** viewhelper. [Example](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-extbasefluid/6.2/en-us/Fluid/ViewHelper/Translate.html#htmlescape)